# sql, inner join and query the result, possible?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have this tables user, problem, subproblem, userdata

I join them together like this:

```
Select * FROM User 
Inner join problem ON user.id = problem.userid
Inner join subproblem ON user.id = subproblem.userid
Inner join userdata ON user.id = userdata.userid
```

In userdata is data like postcode/province

I need al this data but I also need to output a result displaying how many problems a certain province has. How would i go over something like this? Make a seperate query or create a row behind the selected rows counting the problems per province? How would I approach this?

Can you query a query result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The two queries sound a bit unrelated, so my knee-jerk reaction is to run a separate query. But how are you intending to display this data? Do you want a number of problems-per-province *for each subproblem*, or is this going to be a separate table somewhere (else) on the resulting page?

Comment: Also, are you using a particular programming language (e.g. PHP), or are you doing this analysis in a MySQL console?

Comment: Please post all table definitions. As it stands now, there is not enough information to give a definitive query.

Comment: .@TimBiegeleisen has a good point. Unless you're querying the database directly (in which case it wouldn't matter whether you had a separate query or not) you are probably already looping over the result rows. It wouldn't take much more to aggregate by province as you loop, and would be better than getting the database to do extra (perhaps-not-so-)heavy lifting and transfer more data.

Comment: lc: I need only number of problems per province
Tim: its now running in sql server environment console (maybe later in php)

Comment: What would you consider heavy lifting lc? :P doing it like i proposed?

Comment: So running a seperate query is less heavy on the server than doing aforementioned query (which has to be done for other purposes) including a row with problems-per-province?

Comment: An extra query can be very lightweight, depending on index and data size. It should be faster than adding the result to the original query, very much depending on the relation of the data sizes. As I said, if you have many more problems than provinces, use extra query.

Comment: Thanks flaschenpost, tim and lc this answered my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have many more problems than provinces, it would be better to use two seperate queries. You could stuff it into one, but that would mean much more work for database without a real profit.

Also you often do not output the summary data to the user in every result line, and then you have to get the summary data out of the real problem rows.

EDIT: Just a guess for the counting query, since there is no table structure given.

```
select ud.province, count(*) as number_problems
from userdata as ud
left join problem p on p.user_id = ud.user_id
group by ud.province;
```

EDIT2: Just for fun, this is a small (completely untested) idea of how I would do part of it in one query:

```
@set province=NULL;
@set numprobs=NULL;

select isel.province
  , if(@province = isel.province,
        @numprobs := @numprobs+1,
        @numprobs := 1 + if(@province := isel.province, 0, 0)) as numprobs
  , isel.*
from (
    select * FROM User 
    Inner join problem ON user.id = problem.userid
    Inner join subproblem ON user.id = subproblem.userid
    Inner join userdata ON user.id = userdata.userid
    order by userdata.province, userdata.<somedata>
    ) as isel
```

But if you want to order your original data other than by province first, you need another subquery around just for ordering.

The whole query should be processed more or less straightforward, so it should not take much more time, but it will be slower than without variable magic. When you would try to use subqueries, the processing time *can* grow by large factors.

In this fun version you don't get the maximum, but the "this is problem number 23 for that province", and you have to fish out the maximum manually. But of course MySQL could do this also for you (in another inner select box around the query).

Comment: Why wouldn't you just join your first query and the query in the OP, instead of going through some iterative magic dependent on the ordering of the result set?

Comment: @lc my first query uses a `group by`, and if you join that to the original query you might very probably end up firing a big dependend subquery millions of times. The variable magic is very lightweight around the original select.